# Group Record by 15 minutes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to group the records by every 15 minutes based on the time stamp column using the below query, but the first two record difference in only 10 min.

RAILS CODE:

```
select("DATE_FORMAT(reading_on,'%H:%i') as date,
  ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(reading_on)/(900)) as fif ,
  max(power) as total").group("fif").where("imei= #{site}" ).order("fif asc")
```

MYSQL QUERY:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(reading_on,'%H:%i') as date,
  ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(reading_on)/(900)) as fif ,
  max(power) as total FROM `clarodetails` 
WHERE (imei= 353469040778516) 
  AND (date(reading_on) between '2012-11-18 00:00:00' 
  AND '2012-11-18 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY fif 
ORDER BY fif asc LIMIT 15
```

OUTPUT:
[image: OUPPUT]

Comment: an sqlfiddle would be good ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(reading_on) -
      MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(reading_on), 900)), '%H:%i') as fif,
  max(power) as total
FROM `clarodetails` 
WHERE
  (imei= 353469040778516) 
  AND (date(reading_on) >= '2012-11-18')
  AND (date(reading_on) <  '2012-11-19') 
GROUP BY fif 
ORDER BY fif asc LIMIT 15
```

i also prefer not to use `between '2012-11-18 00:00:00' and '2012-11-18 23:59:59'` (you could always miss some records with `reading_on` after 23:59:59 but before midnight...)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the mixing of aggregate and non-aggregate functions. The first result column is not aggregated, so the result set shows the first value of this column which the query encounters. Include the date column in the aggregation:

```
...GROUP BY fif, date...
```